# SSRS 2012 - Matrix - Case Statement creating extra row issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I'm currently doing a report using a Matrix. There's one column within the grouping that is a case statement, which is creating an extra row for the two results.

Basically, I need it to only have one row. If the YearlyAmount, for any year is greater than 5,000 than "Sum Greater Than $5K". If all of them are less than 5,000 then "No". Example:

[Example of the Issue and Desired Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQa5.png)

Is there any way to only show one row? Or to merge these two together and only show "Sum Greater Than $5K".

Here's the Tablix/Matrix structure:
[Report Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHioJ.png)

And the SQL i'm using for the case statement:

```
    (CASE
        WHEN Yearly.Amount > 5000
            THEN 'Sum Greater Than $5K'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END) AS FlagOneYear
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL try this (only if your have a `GROUP BY`):

```
  MAX(CASE
        WHEN Yearly.Amount > 5000
            THEN 'Sum Greater Than $5K'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END) AS FlagOneYear
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The idea worked. I didn't work within the SQL, but what I did was - I removed the one column from the grouping (within the matrix), then added it outside the grouping to the right. Then I added this expression to it

                                                                                                           '=Switch(
     FIRST(MAX(Fields!YearlyAmount.Value)) > 5000, "Sum Greater Than $5K",  
     FIRST(MAX(Fields!YearlyAmount.value)) < 5000,"NO"
     )'


And it worked!!! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Yoseto Glad it helped!